# Migration From jquery-1.11.1.js To jquery-1.12.4.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

> TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
>
> TypeError: $(...).filestyle is not a function

Some method is not supporting in jquery-1.12.4.js Like `.modle()` and `Ajaxsubmit()` .Can you guide me the relevant method for this with jquery-1.12.4.js

Comment: Those are not core jQuery functions. You must be using plugins for those, so they either need to be updated as well, or are not compatible with that version of jQuery (or you're no longer including them, somehow).

Comment: Thanks sir, can you suggest me Which plugins will resolve this issue